# Converting iFrame Business Maps to Javascript API maps for dark mode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe

I have always worked very effortlessly with Google Maps and their iFrame which displays the business on the webpage with their information, [like this](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Google/@40.7429448,-74.0041077,17.41z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sgoogle!3m4!1s0x89c259bf14f1f51f:0xcc1b5ab35bd75df0!8m2!3d40.7414688!4d-74.0033873).

How is this possible with the javascript API? I have succesfully made a dark map with that, but I want to display the business also. Do I have to use another API for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe this is possible using only the google maps api. You could use the Google Places api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details.
Then you would need to create your own display for the information. I dont think there is any way to get this kind of functionality right out of the gate.

Comment: Thanks. I will use the iFrame then with a black and white filter on it.